# permission denied on scripts in ~/bin

Tags: permissions, scripting, executable

I set some additional locations to the `PATH` environment variable in my `~/.bashrc` so that these are included/sourced in logins and non-interactive scripts that are scheduled with `cron`.

I've noticed though that on one system the `PATH` is modified correctly, but none of the scripts within will run despite ownership and permissions being set correctly (as far as I can tell).

```
$ ls -l
total 756
-rw-r-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    300 Sep  6 07:35 backup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    978 Dec 30 10:28 bbc_mpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline 355483 Nov 29 07:31 get_iplayer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    110 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.albums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    114 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.climbing
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    108 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.films
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    125 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.mixes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    117 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.pics
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline    117 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.torrents
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline     95 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.work
```

The contents of one of my scripts, which synchronizes a directory to my NAS to back it up:

```
$ cat ~/bin/rsync.work 
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
/usr/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/work/*  readynas:~/work/.
```

which fails to run when called:

```
$ rsync.work
bash: /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work: Permission denied
```

but works when preceeded with `bash -x` :

```
$ bash -x /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work
+ source /home/slackline/.keychain/kimura-sh
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-P3GL1A3Juwhe/agent.4209
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=4210
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
+ /usr/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/work/android /mnt/work/arch /mnt/work/classes /mnt/work/doc /mnt/work/linux /mnt/work/lost+found /mnt/work/nc151.tar /mnt/work/nc152now-11.rar /mnt/work/personal /mnt/work/ref /mnt/work/scharr 'readynas:~/work/.'
sending incremental file list

sent 1,176,907 bytes  received 19,786 bytes  30,296.03 bytes/sec
total size is 27,852,538,230  speedup is 23,274.59
$ set -x ; ~/bin/rsync.work ; set +x
+ /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work
bash: /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work: Permission denied
+ set +x
$ set -x ; bash -x ~/bin/rsync.work ; set +x
+ bash -x /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work
+ source /home/slackline/.keychain/kimura-sh
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-P3GL1A3Juwhe/agent.4209
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=4210
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
+ /usr/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/work/android /mnt/work/arch /mnt/work/classes /mnt/work/doc /mnt/work/linux /mnt/work/lost+found /mnt/work/nc151.tar /mnt/work/nc152now-11.rar /mnt/work/personal /mnt/work/ref /mnt/work/scharr 'readynas:~/work/.'
sending incremental file list

sent 1,174,755 bytes  received 19,786 bytes  39,165.28 bytes/sec
total size is 27,852,538,230  speedup is 23,316.52
+ set +x
```

My `~/.bashrc` has  the following line in it.

```
$ grep PATH ~/.bashrc
# Additions to system PATH
PATH="/home/slackline/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/stata/:/usr/local/stattransfer/"
export PATH
```

And I can run the `rsync` command at the command line myself (so it's not a case of permission being denied on the SSH connection).

```
$ /usr/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/work/*  readynas:~/work/.
sending incremental file list

sent 1,176,723 bytes  received 19,786 bytes  32,781.07 bytes/sec
total size is 27,852,538,230  speedup is 23,278.17
```

(Backup is obviously up to date).  The version of Bash installed is:

```
$ eix -Ic bash
[I] app-admin/eselect-bashcomp (1.3.6@08/29/13): Manage contributed bash-completion scripts
[I] app-shells/bash (4.2_p45@08/16/13): The standard GNU Bourne again shell
[I] app-shells/bash-completion (2.1@08/28/13): Programmable Completion for bash
[I] app-shells/gentoo-bashcomp (20121024@08/28/13): Gentoo-specific bash command-line completions (emerge, ebuild, equery, repoman, layman, etc)
Found 4 matches.
```

The permissions on the directory (and its structure) are:

```
$ ls -l ~/ | grep bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 slackline slackline 4096 Dec 30 10:29 bin
$ stat -c"%n (%U) %a" / /home /home/slackline /home/slackline/bin
/ (root) 755
/home (root) 755
/home/slackline (slackline) 755
/home/slackline/bin (slackline) 755
```

And an `strace` shows

```
$ strace rsync.work
strace: Can't stat 'rsync.work': No such file or directory
$ echo $PATH
/home/slackline/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.8.2:/usr/games/bin:/usr/local/stata/:/usr/local/stattransfer/:/usr/local/stata/:/usr/local/stattransfer/
$ ls -l ~/bin/ | grep work
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slackline slackline     95 Sep  6 07:35 rsync.work
$ rsync.work 
bash: /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work: Permission denied
```

I can't work out what's going wrong here and would be grateful of any thoughts/ideas on how to trouble shoot this.

EDIT : Tidied up the various edits made in response to questions to hopefully read a bit more coherently and make it easier to follow what I'd tried and how it fits in with Mark Plotnick's solution.

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory? `ls -l .`

Comment: Directory permissions now included, they're owned by slackline:slackline and read/write/execute for owner and read/execute for group and others.

Comment: Can you give us a complete permissions scheme, using `stat -c"%n (%U) %a" / /home /home/slackline /home/slackline/bin` maybe ?

Comment: complete scheme added, can't see anything wrong myself, but I may not have a proper grasp of permissions.

Comment: what does `bash -x /home/slackline/bin/rsync.work` give you ? also try `bash -x  /home/slackline/tmp/android/helium/linux/run.sh`

Comment: Ahha, thats looking promising for `~/bin` but not for the other script, output added above.

Comment: This can be solved by 2 things. 1) what is the shebang line of the script (the very first line which starts with `#!`. 2) the output of `strace rsync.work`.

Comment: 1) all of my scripts in ~/bin/ start with `#!/bin/bash` (was in the example near the top); 2) I've added the output above.

Comment: Is the filesystem containing your home directory mounted `noexec`?

Comment: Nope, never has been `$ grep home /etc/fstab` shows my home partition (mounted via its label which I set myself) as `LABEL=home  /home  ext4 noatime,users  0 4`

Comment: OK, that explains it. `users` implies `noexec`. You need to override that by including `exec` in the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that your home directory's filesystem is mounted with the `users` mount option.

```
$ grep home /etc/fstab
LABEL=home /home ext4 noatime,users 0 4 –
```

The `users` mount option implies `noexec`. From mount(8):

```
users Allow every user to mount and unmount the filesystem.
      This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless 
      overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line 
      users,exec,dev,suid).
```

Comment: Thats solved it, thank you very much.  Was a little too hasty when migrating my install to its new HD and didn't copy over `/etc/fstab` faithfully to the new install, thank you again.